# Using Python, how to convert PHP data in mysql table to JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, python-3.x

I am importing some data from an older php/mysql web application to a python/mysql web application involving images. The php application stored the exif data for each image in a table, and I am trying to convert that data to a JSON format for the python app. The exif data in the php/mysql app is

```
'a:18:{s:4:"Make";s:5:"Canon";s:5:"Model";s:13:"Canon EOS 30D";s:8:"Aperture";s:5:"f/7.1";s:10:"ColorSpace";s:4:"sRGB";s:12:"ExposureBias";s:4:"0 EV";s:15:"ExposureProgram";s:16:"Shutter Priority";s:12:"ExposureTime";s:10:"1/3200 sec";s:5:"Flash";s:8:"No Flash";s:11:"FocalLength";s:5:"70 mm";s:3:"ISO";s:3:"400";s:12:"MeteringMode";s:7:"Pattern";s:8:"DateTime";s:19:"2009:03:29 12:30:23";s:11:"Orientation";s:17:"1: Normal (0 deg)";s:14:"ResolutionUnit";s:4:"Inch";s:11:"xResolution";s:26:"72 dots per ResolutionUnit";s:11:"yResolution";s:26:"72 dots per ResolutionUnit";s:11:"Compression";s:16:"Jpeg Compression";s:12:"ExposureMode";s:1:"0";}'
```

When I use python exif on the same image, I ge the following JSON format, which is what I want.

```
{"make": "Canon", "flash": {"reserved": 0, "flash_mode": "COMPULSORY_FLASH_SUPPRESSION", "flash_fired": false, "flash_return": "NO_STROBE_RETURN_DETECTION_FUNCTION", "flash_function_not_present": false, "red_eye_reduction_supported": false}, "model": "Canon EOS 30D", "datetime": "2009:03:31 07:35:00", "f_number": 7.1, "software": "Adobe Photoshop 7.0", "color_space": 1, "compression": 6, "orientation": 1, "exif_version": "0221", "focal_length": 70, "user_comment": "", "x_resolution": 72, "y_resolution": 72, "exposure_time": 0.0003125, "metering_mode": 5, "aperture_value": 5.6556396484375, "resolution_unit": 2, "exposure_program": 4, "_exif_ifd_pointer": 212, "datetime_original": "2009:03:29 12:30:23", "pixel_x_dimension": 800, "pixel_y_dimension": 1167, "datetime_digitized": "2009:03:29 12:30:23", "shutter_speed_value": 11.64385986328125, "y_and_c_positioning": 2, "jpeg_interchange_format": 994, "focal_plane_x_resolution": 3959.322033898305, "focal_plane_y_resolution": 3959.322033898305, "photographic_sensitivity": 400, "focal_plane_resolution_unit": 2, "jpeg_interchange_format_length": 1286}
```

I realize there is more data in the python generated exif data; I will take care of that separately.

What is the encoding format in the php app? Is there a way other than direct string manipulations to remove all the a:{number}, s:{number} and associated extra characters?

Thanks!

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/phpserialize/ should do the conversion, but also don't store serialized data in the database even if it _is_ JSON. Normalize it into an actual table structure.

Comment: I used pip install phpserialize and tried some of the examples on the pypi.org page. The first example worked, the second one failed. `loads(dumps(range(2)))` resulted in an exception in phpserialize: builtins.TypeError: can't serialize <class 'range'>. It looks like it should do the trick for me,  but it does not seem to work?

Comment: Looking through the issues on the github account, it looks like the project was built for Python2.7, and is broken for Python 3. I was able to get something close to what I need this way:` sam = loads(b'''a:2:{s:3:"foo";i:1;s:3:"bar";i:2;}''',array_hook=OrderedDict)` then `dict(sam)` returns `{b'foo': 1, b'bar': 2}`. Without the prefix b''', the loads throws an exception. Just letting future readers know caveat emptor applies.

Comment: After a little more reading in the issues for the project, I found that this works on python 3.6.9: `loads(text.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict'),decode_strings=True)`, where text is the data to be converted. Hope that helps some future reader.